# Регулярное выражение для замены одинарной кавычки

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js

У меня есть строка.

```
'We're looking for someone who can assist in completing our mobile app'
```

Для запись в базу данных мне надо ее привести к виду.

```
'We''re looking for someone who can assist in completing our mobile app'
```

Я сделаю регулярное выражение.

```
/["']
```

Проблема в том что он заменяет все кавычки.

```
''We''re looking for someone who can assist in completing our mobile app''
```

Какое условие надо добавить в регулярное выражение, чтобы не заменялись первый и последние элементы, то есть кавычки, а в самом теле заменялись кавычки, вне зависимости от их количества.

Comment: Передавайте литерал как параметр, а не вставляйте в текст запроса.

Comment: Если строка __обязательно__ начинается и заканчивается на кавычку, их можно исключить перед обработкой и позже вернуть. Если строка __может__ содержать кавычки в начале и в конце, уже появляется неопределенность. Как обрабатывать такое выражение `'первая строка в кавычках' текст между кавычками 'вторая строка в кавычках'`?

Comment: Тут не нужен lookbehind, сойдёт и `s.replace(/(?!^)'(?!$)/g, "''")`

Comment: Меня одного смущает сама постановка вопроса? Зачем для записи в базу надо экранировать кавычки? Есть очень сильные подозрения, что Вы делаете что-то не так.

Comment: @Yaant Мне нужно записать это строку в бд, и postgresql выдает ошибку. `синтаксическая ошибка около we'`. Так как он все что после `'` воспринимает как другой аргумент, необходимо экранировать кавычку.

Comment: Я и говорю, что-то делаете не так. Вы, похоже, собираете строку запроса целиком? Так делать не надо, чревато SQL-инъекциями. Используйте параметризованные запросы, и проблема отпадет сама самой.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не склеивайте SQL вручную - это чревато SQL инъекциями. Используйте параметризированные запросы. В случае pg это что-то вроде:

```
const text = 'INSERT INTO sometable(somecolumn) VALUES($1)'
const values = ["'We're looking for someone who can assist in completing our mobile app'"]

client.query(text, values, (err, res) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err.stack)
  } else {
    console.log(res.rows[0])
  }
})
```